# ajax checkbox not passing my data to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to update my database data using checked box with ajax. the checkbox is running when I clicked it alert the success msg. but not passing the data to my controller. I don't know where to find my mistake here. I'm trying to figure out how to check if the data is pass to my controller.

Anyone can help me?

view

```
$checked = FALSE;
if($result->consignment == 1) { $checked = TRUE; }
    $data = array(
        'value'   => $result->id, 
        'onClick' => 'incoming_CheckboxState();',
        'class'   => 'incoming',
        'checked' => $checked
    );
echo form_checkbox($data);?> Incoming
```

ajax

```
function incoming_CheckboxState() {
  if ($('.incoming').is(':checked')) {

    var id = $('.incoming').val();
    var yes = 1;                
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?=based_url(); ?>user_accounts/update_permission",
        data: { user_id : id, status : yes },
        success: function(msg) {
            alert("Activated");
        }
    });
  } 
}
```

controller

```
public function update_permission(){
    $data = array(
       'id' => $this->input->post('user_id'),
        'status' => $this->input->post('status')
    );
    $this->user_accounts_model->incoming($data);
}
```

model

```
public function incoming($data){
    $this->db->set('consignment', $data['status'])
             ->where('id', $data['id'])
             ->update('users');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these

1. Change AJAX URL

   ```
   url: "<?=base_url()?>user_accounts/update_permission"
   ```
2. Set your `base_url`.(`application/config/config.php`)

   ```
   $config['base_url'] = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
   ```

Comment: this is my base_url   = $config['base_url'] = '';

Comment: dont leave base URL empty. fill it

Comment: What's the effect if the based url is empty? I saw in tutorial they make it empty. and what URL should I put incase?

Comment: In CI3 URL is must, else you program can be hacked using URL Injection. Base url should be path to your root folder.(outside application folder..)

Comment: for example my main folder is ci_attl

Comment: assume `htdocs\aaa\application` then project Base URL should be  ***`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/aaa';`***

Comment: xampp\htdocs\ci_attl\application   now all link css not working

Comment: it goes back to normal now, but checkbox still not working sir.. can we chat sir?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136463/discussion-between-abdulla-nilam-and-genina-anne-gabuten).

Comment: abdulla check chat i sent the link

Answer (score 0):

```
url: "<?=based_url()?>./user_accounts/update_permission",
```

Should be (Your base url in config.php should be set with a trailing slash):

```
url: "<?= base_url(); ?>user_accounts/update_permission",
```

Where are you getting that . from?

Open your inspector, go to network and click on XHR to monitor ajax requests being made (so you can see if the request is made and if your post data is there as well).

Comment: it's still not working,  in my network, i have form data user_id: 1 status: 1 ,,

Comment: http://[::1]/ci_attl/user_accounts/user_permission/%3C?=based_url();?%3E/user_accounts/update_permission  this is the request URL

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten Seems your base url isn't set properly.